# pdfminer odd result with a two columns pdf

Tags: python, xml, pdf, pdfminer

I'm converting somes pdf documents to text and for it I'm using pdfminer (using pdf2txt.py). I'm not converting directly from pdf to txt, because I want to signal formats such as italics or bold. Therefore I first convert the pdf to xml. 
I'm converting pdf to xml using:

> pdf2txt.py -t xml -o out_file.xml in_file.pdf

My problem is that I found an odd error in the xml file when converting this [pdf](http://app.parlamento.pt/darpages/dardoc.aspx?doc=6148523063446f764c324679626d56304c334e706447567a4c315a4a53556c4d5a576376524546535353394551564a4a51584a7864576c32627938784c734b714a5449775532567a63384f6a627955794d45786c5a326c7a6247463061585a684c305242556b6b774d7a41756347526d&nome=DARI030.pdf). If you convert it to xml, check the following:

1. In page 21 of the pdf the second column starts with "Recentemente...".
2. The first paragraph of the first column (of the same page) ends with "...lhes falta".
3. The resulting converting xml file contains the item 1. (and full column) just after item 2. You can check it in line 128370 of the xml file. Then in line 131782 the correct order starts again, i.e., the paragraph that starts with "O terceiro..." follows.

So, my question is if there is a solution to avoid this error.